# returning single result using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datarow

I have a query

```
row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
  .Where(categoryRow => categoryRow["event_id"].ToString() == eventObject.EventId.ToString())
  .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x["category_id"].ToString()))
```

This query returns an IEnumerable. I am expecting an 'int'

Help me modify my LINQ query

Comment: however this returns a DataRowCollection which is not what I am expecting to return bot an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect your query only to return a single value use the [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) extension method.

```
row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
   .Where(categoryRow => categoryRow["event_id"].ToString() == eventObject.EventId.ToString())
   .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x["category_id"].ToString()))
   .Single();
```

Note that [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) will throw an exception if there is no value. If that is not what you want, use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx).

Comment: return value will be Int32, he is parsing the string to Int32

Answer (score 1):

You can always add this to the end of your query:

```
.Single();
```

That will return the one value if your enumerable contains only one, or throw an exception if it contains another amount than one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data add `.FirstOrDefault`, `.SingleOrDefault()`, `.First()` etc.

```
ow.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
  .Where(categoryRow => categoryRow["event_id"].ToString() == eventObject.EventId.ToString())
  .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x["category_id"].ToString())).FirstOrDefault()
```

When you expect multiple rows, use First (`FirstOrDefault` if you dont want an exception if there is no data returned).  Multiple rows will throw an exception on `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `First()` clause to the query:

```
row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
  .Where(categoryRow => categoryRow["event_id"].ToString() == eventObject.EventId.ToString())
  .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x["category_id"].ToString()))
  .First()
```

You may want to use `FirstOfDefault()` in case there are no results, as `First()` will throw an exception in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

just `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Select()`, keep in mind if there more than one result you will get an exception, you can also use`FirstOrDefault()`,so it will look like:

```
row.GetChildRows("EventCategoryRelation")
.Where(categoryRow => categoryRow["event_id"].ToString() == eventObject.EventId.ToString())
.SingleOrDefault(x => Int32.Parse(x["category_id"].ToString()))
```